# The value in the edit field keeps changing to default value when I change the comboBox value in AutoHotKey

Tags: python-3.x, drop-down-menu, automation

I am trying to automate entering inputs to a software using AutoHotKey. One of the input parameters is a drop down list. And another is a text field. I first need to fill the text field then select a drop down option. Once the drop drown option changes, the new value for the same text field needs to be inputted. Doing this manually doesn't alter the previous text value.

That is say I choose option 1 and enter "hello world"
Then I choose option 2 and enter "hi world"
Let us say the default value is "default"

The functionality of the software is such that it maintains the text value as associated with the options as we enter it.
so I can go back and forth between the options and the text value displays accordingly.

However when I try to automate this, the previously entered text gets altered to the default value. And if I go back and forth between options, the values become defaulted.

I have used python to run the autohotkey script. I have also upload part of the code and a few images for clarity.

AHK code:

```
SetControlDelay -1
ControlSetText, Edit7, 452000, ahk_exe PerRoad44.exe
SetControlDelay -1
Control, Choose, 3, ComboBox1, ahk_exe PerRoad44.exe
ControlSetText, Edit7, 452000, ahk_exe PerRoad44.exe
```

python code:

```
import autopy
from ahk import AHK
from Configuration import Config

ahk = AHK()

ahk.run_script('Run ' + Config.SOFTWARE_PATH)
ahk = AHK()
winStructInputTab = ahk.find_window(title=b'PerRoad 4.4')
winStructInputTab.send(autopy.key.tap(autopy.key.Code.F1)) # this opens up the input tab of the software
ahk.run_script('SetWinDelay, 10')
ahk.run_script('SetWinDelay, 1000')
f = open(r"h2.ahk", "r")
ahk_script = f.read()
print(ahk_script)
ahk.run_script(ahk_script, blocking=False)
```

I couldn't find any solution to this. Please help me figure this out.
Thank you

[Current season is the drop down and modulus is the text field I'm trying to set the value for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccSP6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have found an solution to the problem from the link (https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/48737-changing-the-value-of-an-edit-control-which-is-taken-over/).

The modified code should be of the following type:

```
ControlClick, Edit7, ahk_exe PerRoad44.exe
ControlSetText, Edit7,,ahk_exe PerRoad44.exe
ControlClick, Edit7, ahk_exe PerRoad44.exe
ControlSend, Edit7, {Home}+{End}, ahk_exe PerRoad44.exe
Control, EditPaste, 55000, Edit7, ahk_exe PerRoad44.exe

ControlFocus, ComboBox1, ahk_exe PerRoad44.exe
Control, Choose, 3, ComboBox1, ahk_exe PerRoad44.exe

ControlClick, Edit7, ahk_exe PerRoad44.exe
ControlSetText, Edit7,,ahk_exe PerRoad44.exe
ControlClick, Edit7, ahk_exe PerRoad44.exe
ControlSend, Edit7, {Home}+{End}, ahk_exe PerRoad44.exe
Control, EditPaste, 55000, Edit7, ahk_exe PerRoad44.exe
```

This solved my problem.